# React AXIOS post - simple test not working (express)

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, express, axios

I have a built react front end, I used a simple boilerplate to connect the express with react. There seems to be SO many different ways to setup a SIMPLE RESTful api that I'm getting lost. I'm trying to do some very simple backend to front end communication.

I have express do a get request to push to the back and am using Axios to get the data:

AccountsDB is just basic JSON data for internal testing

```
[
  {
    "id": "5b68d6f13e2c773581221620",
    "index": 0,
    "firstName": "Josefa",
    "lastName": "Lynch",
    "pin" : 1234
  }
]
```

Inside my express index.js I have a simple GET

```
app.get('/api/getAccounts', (req, res) => res.json(AccountsDB));
```

within my React I fetch the data with axois:

```
componentDidMount () {
    axios.get ('/api/getAccounts')
    .then (res => this.setState({ Accounts : res.data}));
}
```

Totally works. I display the account within the main react component. 
Inside the component I also have a forum to "create" a a new account, and push it to the *AccountsDB* file just for internal testing (I'm learning backend, will connect mongoDB after).

My logic for POST method (found here [Axios Cheet Sheet](https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/Axios.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index)):

```
    axios.post('/api/putAccounts', {
        firstName: 'Fred',
        lastName: 'Flintstone'
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Which I attach onto a button to post the data. I open up POST man and navigate to '/api/putAccounts' and see nothing.

I don't understand how to exactly *gather* the data into express. My silly attempt :

```
app.post('/api/putAccounts', (req,res) => {
    // res.send("sent!") // post man see's this?
    // var account = req.account;
    // res.send(req.firstName);
});
```

**To elaborate in more detail ...**

React app is on   -> localhost:3000

Express app is on -> localhost:8080

using webpack and a proxy:

```
 devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api': 'http://localhost:8080'
    }
```

under 'http://localhost:3000/admin' (in my react app) I have a button that has the `axios.post` that send the firstName : Fred and lastName : Flintstone to `'/api/putAccounts'`

I'm trying to have my express server catch the post so I can manipulate it and add it into a database.

Before I get into database stuff, I'm trying to make sure I understand how POST works (I understand GET). So I'm trying to get the data, and display it somewhere, this is what I mean by viewing it in postman.

Maybe I'm going about this all wrong, hence why the confusion.

Comment: You need to access it using req.body.firstName and req.body.lastName in serverside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In postman you need to send firstName and lastName in req body like below while making post request

```
  {
      "firstName": "Hi",
      "lName": "Hello"
  }
```

So that you can do req.body.firstName to get its value  below

```
  app.post('/api/putAccounts', (req,res) => {
       const fName = req.body.firstName;
       const lName = req.body.lastName;
       res.json({"fName":fName, "lastName": lName});
  });
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me, I just have a empty object "{}" in postman.

My console does say {data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …} when I press the "POST" button I created.

Comment: Why do you want to send an empty object in post request. It doesn’t make sense. You need to understand the purpose of post request

Comment: What are you expecting from us?

Comment: I created a button within my react app that does the axios POST (  axios.post('/api/putAccounts', {
        firstName: 'Fred',
        lastName: 'Flintstone'
    })
 etc .. (as seen in my post) 

I'm trying to get my backend to catch the "fred flitstone" that I'm sending with my frontend.  My issue in understanding is how am I supposed to add new data to my DB when I'm having trouble grabbing it with my express server form my react app.

Comment: Please be specific. Grabbing about what? What is your exact issue in Express backend?

Comment: First, be sure that your backend works properly. Do you set a `body` when you try with Postman?

Comment: @devserkan what do you mean by 'set a body'. I've aded more information to my question.

Comment: I mean, do you provide a proper body while testing with postman?

Comment: @devserkan he is not. In one of his comment he mentioned that he is sending an empty object in post Api call from postman. Please check his first comment under my answer

Comment: Actually, I've seen that comment but I couldn't understand what this empty object means. Response or body?

Comment: So extra description helped. I completely misunderstood on how this works.
I thought the setup is such as this: I clicked the button on react app, express grabs it and send the response to POSTMAN (which I view). But, I realized now I send a post via postman to express and it sends a response back.  Which it did, so it does work.

Comment: It’s about req body because his code doesn’t return anything. So I assumed it’s req body

Comment: @RobertOchinski, your backend, and your frontend actually two separate things. You can send data from frontend via your React app. This is fine but people generally test their backend without writing any frontend code. Postman is used for testing without a frontend. So, when testing with Postman you need to provide the data yourself for a post request. Write backend first, test with Postman, then write your frontend code, then test from the frontend.